# Is there a way to block answers from low-reputation users?

Tags: support, questions, answers, reputation

Several times I got spam answers which are not correct. And seems that understand my question properly. And most of spam answers from low reputation users.

Is there a way to ask a question and set the users to answer when the user has more than 100 reputation?

Comment: How do you suppose someone would get to 100 rep if they couldn't answer in the first place? Answers are what help new users become experienced... it makes 0 sense to judge based on rep anyway. What if Jon Skeet's clone created a new account? Jon Skeet's clone would be incredibly knowledgable but be unable to assist because he just started. Rep is a bad measurement of knowledge.

Comment: You only have 5 questions that I can see. 4 of them have got a single answer and one zero and you have accepted all of these answers. Where is the spam you speak of?

Comment: I'm with @Martin Smith. Looking at the questions you've asked, and the answers they're received, I don't see any that are spam or garbage. There are no answers that have been deleted by moderators in response to flags, and you seem quite happy with the answers you've received (except maybe for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45526170/366904), and that's not by a low-rep user).

Comment: I would argue that restricting low rep users from asking would be more beneficial, as low quality questions are more harmful than low quality answers. This would result in fewer duplicates and user having to learn the site in order to ask.

Answer (score 23):

If you don't find an answer useful, downvote it. Questions and answers are the life-blood of the site, we will *never* use reputation as a criteria for asking or answering questions.

Comment: Except in the case of [protected questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354674/2288578) ;)

Comment: @Clonkex This is done to prevent *literal* spam, not low-quality answers

Answer (score 17):

If you're getting a lot of actual *spam* in a given question, it can be Protected - this blocks answers from users with under 10 rep.

For more info, see: [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

Answer (score 9):

If you get an answer that's literally spam (undisclosed promotion of a product or service) you should flag it as "spam". If it's noise or complete garbage, flag it as "very low quality". You can also leave a comment asking for clarification/improvement low-quality answers. And, of course, you should always downvote them.

Besides, there are plenty of cases where first posts end up being absolutely stellar; for example, I saw a [superb question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928556/why-explicitly-throw-a-nullpointerexception-rather-than-letting-it-happen-natura) from a new user that currently has a score of 165 (and a score of 237 on the top answer). A lot of new users have very valuable contributions; we should be *encouraging* new people to contribute, not discouraging it.